# Minimum value in each row and each column of a matrix - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, matrix, min

Can someone please help me out? I am trying to get the minimum value of each row and of each column of this matrix

```
matrix =[[12,34,28,16],
        [13,32,36,12],
        [15,32,32,14],
        [11,33,36,10]]
```

So for example: I would want my program to print out that 12 is the minimum value of row 1 and so on.

Comment: you can iterate row wise and column wise. and get max and min for each row and column. First try to get min for each row, then max as well. Then do it for column wise. ATB :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix =[[12,34,28,16],
...         [13,32,36,12],
...         [15,32,32,14],
...         [11,33,36,10]]
>>> np.min(matrix, axis=1) # computes minimum in each row 
array([12, 12, 14, 10])
>>> np.min(matrix, axis=0) # computes minimum in each column
array([11, 32, 28, 10])
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's repeat the task statement: "get the minimum value of *each row* and of *each column* of this matrix".

Okay, so, if the matrix has `n` rows, you should get `n` minimum values, *one for each row*. Sounds interesting, doesn't it? So, the code'll look like this:

```
result1 = [<something> for row in matrix]
```

Well, what do you need to do with each row? Right, find the minimum value, which is super easy:

```
result1 = [min(row) for row in matrix]
```

As a `result`, you'll get a list of `n` values, just as expected.

---

Wait, by now we've only found the minimums for each row, but not for each *column*, so let's do this as well!

Given that you're using Python 3.x, you can do some pretty amazing stuff. For example, you can loop over columns easily:

```
result2 = [min(column) for column in zip(*matrix)] # notice the asterisk!
```

The asterisk in `zip(*matrix)` makes each row of `matrix` a separate argument of `zip`'s, like this:

```
zip(matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3])
```

This doesn't look very readable and is dependent on the number of rows in `matrix` (basically, you'll have to hard-code them), and the asterisk lets you write much cleaner code.

`zip` returns tuples, and the `i`th tuple contains the `i`th values of *all* the rows, so these tuples are actually the columns of the given matrix.

---

Now, you may find this code a bit ugly, you may want to write the same thing in a more concise way. Sure enough, you can use some functional programming magic:

```
result1 = list(map(min, matrix))
result2 = list(map(min, zip(*matrix)))
```

These two approaches are absolutely equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I very very much appreciate it. :)